# SSHD is asking for a passphrase for my key whereas there is no passphrase

Tags: git, ssh

A lot of topics seems to be related to my issue. But none of them solved my problem:

I have copied my SSH private key to a new server. I have never set a passphrase for it.
But now when I try to connect to Gitlab (from my server) it asks for a password.

```
ssh -v -i /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa git@gitlab.com
[...]
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/john/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

If I create a brand new pair of keys. It perfectly works! But I want to keep my current key.
On the client side, the rights are good:
- .ssh -> 700
- id_rsa -> 600

I am running a fresh Centos 7.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your private key is presumably not in the exact format that SSH requires.  Make sure that it begins with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and ends with `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` *exactly*.

Comment: When I saw your answer, I told myself "How this man can say something stupid like this?". Well, I was the stupid man :D     My private key file missed the "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" part. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: If I could say *unbelievable* and *incredible* in 10 different languages, I would.  I had the exact same problem and it has been annoying me for YEARS.  Tacking on the `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` closing stanza made it go away immediately!